# How to see if a value or object is in a QuerySet field

Tags: django

How would I see if a value is in a QuerySet?

For example, if I have the following model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

How would I find out if the first_name 'David' is contained in a QuerySet? A way to do the following:

```
ld = UserProfile.objects.filter(...).values('first_name')
    >>> for object in ld:
    ...     if object['first_name'] =='David':
    ...             print True
```

Or if a particular user object is instead? Something like `'David' in QuerySet['first_name']` ? Thank you.

Comment: Why would you not do that in `filter()`?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Simplest way is to use the `get` method of the manager:

```
try:
    foo = Foo.objects.get(foo_name='David')
except Foo.DoesNotExist:
    print 'Nope'
except Foo.MultipleObjectsReturned:
    print 'Filter is a better choice here'
```

The `exists` method is applicable also, if you don't need to get the object:

```
if Foo.objects.filter(foo_color='green').exists():
    print 'Nice'
```

If you already have the object and want to determine if it is contained in a queryset:

```
foo = Foo.objects.get(foo_name='David')
qs = Foo.objects.filter(<criteria>)
if foo in qs:
    print 'Nice again'
```

If you want to use a value instead of an object:

```
value = 'David'
qs = Foo.objects.filter(<criteria>).values_list('foo_name',flat=True)
if value in qs:
    print 'Nice'
```

Comment: thanks this is really helpful. A couple of questions: 1) what is the difference between using `if Foo.objects.filter(...):` and `if Foo.objects.filter(...).exists()` -- is `.exists()` substantially faster? 2) what does `flat=True` do / why would you use that in the `.values()` criteria? Thank you.

Comment: 1) Filter returns a queryset, exists returns True or False based on whether the queryset has any records or not. 2) If flat=True, values method returns a list of single items, otherwise returns a list of tuples. For further details you can consult to the excellent queryset documentation.

Comment: ok thanks. I looked at the docs and did some testing and it's `.values_list()` that returns a list of tuples or a list of single items if `flat=True`. .values() doesn't offer `flat=True` (I looked at the docs when I got an error message from it).

Comment: Using `in` is often/usually a bad idea though, as it evaluates the `QuerySet` - it's better to do something like `queryset.filter(<criteria>).filter(id=david.id).exists()`.

Answer (score 1):

in Django >= 4.0, `contains(obj)` can be used, that is faster

```
if some_queryset.contains(obj):
    print('Entry contained in queryset')
```

The documentation also says this is faster than the following.

```
if obj in some_queryset:
    print('Entry contained in queryset')
```